# Did Chester Gould actually confirm that breathless Mahoney was visually based on Veronica lake?

Tags: history-of, inspiration

Breathless Mahoney from the Dick Tracy comic  strip is said to be modelled after actress Veronica Lake.

Is it true or just people’s assumptions? Has Chester Gould ever confirm that?

Comment: It's mentioned in a book by  Garyn G Roberts Dick Tracy and American Culture: Morality and Mythology, Text and Context. It seems to be an assumption though and not directly linked to Chester Gould in this work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please note that this site is for questions about works of science fiction and fantasy, or about science fictional or fantasy aspects of borderline works.  I'm not sure this question is really on-topic for the site.

Comment: @DavidW - Dick Tracy seems pretty firmly on topic. At one point he had a space car and adventures on the moon

Comment: The question is about a science fiction character you may look it up

Comment: The Moon people are back in some recent strips.